# Why is my GTM click ID trigger firing on ALL clicks?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've setup my trigger as per the screenshot below, yet a click is being registered on every single click on the page. Once I delete this trigger, the clicks stop registering.

Has anyone seen this before? I'm new to GTM.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is gtm.click then it should be just fine . I attached a screen shot here . If you see the something like this when you click any where on the page then it is fine . Gtm automaticlly trigger this event when you implement any onclick trigger

[gtm.click example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlqI.png)

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the answer.